# Is node.js good for non-server applications, e.g. command line scripts?

Tags: node.js

I believe node is a fast I/O non-blocking platform, which sounds like it does not have to be only network applications.

So I wonder if there are any cases of which using node, not as a server, would be of benefit? E.g. for writing command-line programs.

Comment: i'm not sure I follow - what is meant by `e.g. SysAdmin`

Comment: Command-line apps/scripts

Comment: Thanks Paul for the edit :)

Comment: I dont see how this question can be opinion-based. I'm only seeking examples from expert and experienced people! I'm not asking "what is better" or " this vs. that".

Comment: There certainly are lots of non-server applications written in Node.js. At the company I work for, we use Node.js programs for build/deployment of applications, for testing, and for a number of system administration tasks. Whether or not Node is (or should be) "good" for writing command-line tools is something of a matter of opinion, and also of vigorous debate within the Node.js community.

Answer (score 2):

[Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) is a great example. It's a JS task runner that most people use as a build tool. Unless you make it run a server for you, you will communicate with it solely via CLI.